# Do I need to be skilled in all / most aspects of the site to be a (good) moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I often find myself not knowing the correct course of action with the privileges given to me thanks to my 20k+ (Stack Overflow) reputation.

- Should I flag this answer?
- Should I vote to delete that?
- Should I vote to close this?
- Which reason should I use for that?
- etc.

Thankfully (or unfortunately?) I'm not particularly inclined to do the something just to do something, so the result of the above is often inaction (there are probably too many such occurrences to flag for moderator attention or ask a Meta question about it ... or perhaps there isn't).

I'm sure everyone has the above problem occasionally (if not, I'd be worried), but I suspect I have this problem a bit more than most.

*Apart* from the above, I think I possess qualities of a great moderator (which I perhaps shouldn't get into, to prevent this from getting too localized).

So, should I consider this a deal-breaker and not even consider nominating myself as a moderator and/or would the above be tested/validated during the election process so I don't really have to worry?

I do think I know enough to be able to do quite a bit of good as a moderator, presumably on the same scale as other moderators - my concern is more towards - do I need to be able to handle just about any issue, or can I be a good moderator even if I'm only able to handle certain issue?

Just to add - I don't think I'll make the *wrong* choice a whole lot (though we all make mistakes), I'll tend more towards admitting to myself that I'm not sure, and letting another moderator handle it.

Comment: Well, you should be skilled in , say , 80% of them

Comment: I've seen your work. I'd vote for you.

Answer (score 14):

Without specific examples it would be hard to give you a reading, but I can give you some general guidelines.

Firstly, its impossible to keep up with every possible intricacy that's being discussed on Meta, nor should you have to.  What remains is a fairly simple set of foundational moderation principles.

The role of moderators is to handle situations that the community is unable or unwilling to handle themselves.  (well, and to sweep the floor, clean up the vomit, etc.)  To keep the decision making process from being unwieldy, I follow a singular guiding principle:

> Does this hurt the site if I leave it here?

Inaction is a valid moderator decision.  Sometimes I'll leave it to the community to sort out.  For what it's worth, a good portion of what I've learned about being a good moderator I learned *after I became one.*

Comment: Is there an introduction/training for new moderators?

Comment: @Pëkka Does hazing count as an introduction?

Comment: @Pëkka: It's called the deep end of the pool.  There's a bit of written guidance, and it takes the existing mods a week or two in the Teacher's Lounge to get folks up to speed.  Mostly, new mods usually know nearly everything they need to know to be reasonably effective (having been active community members for awhile), and we answer any remaining questions about specific intricacies in the Teacher's Lounge.  It takes a day or two to learn the new tools.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody has the perfect answer to everything. But you probably should be confident that you would make a pretty good decision **most of the time**.

Additionally the team takes time to [utilize a new moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135427/172011).

And there is always the moderator chat rooms which are probably used plenty.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to bear in mind. I would say being skilled in one area of the site is a pre-requisite to moderate effectively - but the sites would be far worse off if it were a requirement to have broad knowledge of all aspects of the site. For some of the larger sites, that's not even possible.

Just as security is less of a sequence of steps you take once, but more of a mindset and a way to approach each decision you make on an ongoing basis -- moderation is more of a toolset and frame of mind than simply the go-no go decisions you pile up as you act on posts. If you examine posts that are not clear to you - you'd want to step up as a moderator if you are interested in *learning* how to handle them or *collaborating* with others to both learn and build a framework whereby these decisions become easier.

Also, there is a big difference between most community moderation where one single vote doesn't cause a state to change. Flags have an initiator and a handler. Many votes take 2/3 or more consensus to change the state. Elected moderators will tend to take a "wait and see" case on things that are borderline and also have the ability to rescind immediately many moderator actions.

So - the best way to get good at moderation is work with others. Elected mods have formal agreements to review, some tools and access to other moderators to both ease their transition from community moderation to elected moderation, but most of those same tools exist for all moderators. Meta, chat rooms and comments when constructive all will help and for the most part, grace under pressure, thick skin and a compassionate outlook are far more important than being an expert with wide domain expertise when it comes time to decide if someone is acting as a good moderator or a great moderator.